# ImageMagick - Merge and center multiple images

Tags: command-line, imagemagick

I am trying to append multiple PNG files, which are of different dimensions, into a single combined image.

I want individual 'layers' to be centered.

This is what I am trying to achieve in pictorial form:

[image: .]

A simple:

```
convert a.png b.png c.png -flatten combined.png
```

results in:

[image: .]

...and I was able to center everything by manually specifying offsets (`'-page +X+Y'`) but I was wondering if there is an automatic way of achieving this.

Comment: Unless b.png and c.png are the same height and width as a.png, then you have to specify x and y.

Answer (score 8):

You can avoid the temporary file by compositing `b.png` onto `a.png` and then `c.png` on top of that like this:

```
convert -gravity center a.png b.png -composite c.png -composite result.png
```

[image]

Comment: In my case, transparent background become solid black after `composite`.

Comment: @林果皞 that is probably an issue with your imagemagick version not being able to handle transparency properly. I had the same problem.
You can check if your imagemagick installation handles transparency correct by:
convert -size 100x100 xc:none transparent.png
Sidenote: jpg images can not handle transparency.

Answer (score 6):

Better but still not the best solution because of temporary image:

```
composite -gravity center  b.png a.png temp.png \
&& \
composite -gravity center c.png temp.png composite.png
```

Comment: I had to shuffle the filenames around (`composite -gravity center b.png a.png temp.png && composite -gravity center c.png temp.png composite.png`), but it worked, thanks for the idea!